# ace:tabSet style is corrupted when using ICEFaces 3

Tags: icefaces

hi when using **icefaces 2** the following image was the look of my tabs

[image]

and after migrating to **icefaces 3** the look of my tab becomes as follows:

[image]

**ace:tabSet** code:

```
<ace:tabSet clientSide="true" id="permissionsTab">
<c:forEach items="#{myBean.tabs}" var="tab" varStatus="loop">               

                  <ace:tabPane>
                    <f:facet name="label">#{tab.name}</f:facet>             
                    <div style="height:180px; overflow:auto;">
                       <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{tab.values}" layout="pageDirection" >
                           <f:selectItems value="#{tab.checkBoxes}" />
                       </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                       </div>
                  </ace:tabPane>

                </c:forEach>

           </ace:tabSet>
```

-and here's how i am using the skin for icefaces 2:

```
<h:head>
  <link href="./xmlhttp/css/xp/xp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</h:head>

<h:body styleClass="ice-skin-rime">
</h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet library="org.icefaces.component.skins" name="rime.css" />
```

and when i moved to icefaces 3, i had to remove the following line:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="org.icefaces.component.skins" name="rime.css" />
```

please advise how to fix the style in icefaces 3.

Comment: i bet issue here is with incompatible `rime.css`, can you add icefaces 3 compatible `rime.css` and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: you will have to look for icefaces 3 compatible rime.css and see if your css is the same one or different, if different then you might want to check on the versions of the jars you have.

Comment: icefaces does some nasty things if you don't have proper related jars...

Answer (score 0):

to get it working, i used a workaround by **copying the rime style** from the extracted **icefaces-ace jar**: in the path **org\icefaces\icefaces-ace\3.0.0\META-INF\resources\icefaces.ace\themes\rime\theme.css**
and put it in my css folder, and load it manually using:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="theme.css" library="css" />
```

and copied the images in the rime folder too and put it in my images folder, and adjusted the url of the images in the theme.css file.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/9768194/164299, i have posted answer there, i had similar issue where `rime.css` was not getting referenced but i was able to fix it with the solution posted.