# How to configure rime style in ICEfaces 3

Tags: icefaces

in icefaces 2 i was configuring rime style as follows:

```
<h:head>
  <link href="./xmlhttp/css/xp/xp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</h:head>

<h:body styleClass="ice-skin-rime">
</h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet library="org.icefaces.component.skins" name="rime.css" />
```

and i was wondering how to configure it in icefaces 3
because i tried the following and it doesn't work

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.ace.theme</param-name>
        <param-value>rime</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

please advise thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way as you did it for `xp.css`, try

```
<h:head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css" />
</h:head>
```

it should work, let me know if you still have any issues, make sure you have `/xmlhttp` rather than `./xmlhttp`

Comment: I am using `icefaces3` have no issues referencing `rime.css`, also what `browser` you are opening your `url`?